# Unresolved circular reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

I have two databases projects in a single solution, Database A and Database B.  They both have queries that point to each other like this

```
Select * FROM [Database A].dbo.Table
```

Visual Studio will give you a warning like this SQL04151: Procedure xyz contains an unresolved reference to an object......  This warning is resolved in Database B if you add a database reference to Database A.

However, there are still warnings from Database A complaining about an unresolved reference to something in Database B.

If I try to add a reference to Database B from Database A it won't let me because it says 'A reference to library 'Database B' cannot be added.   Adding this project as a reference would cause a circular dependency.

So I guess my question is how to I resolve the reference so that the warnings will stop be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

In VS2010 DB Projects, you want to generate a *.DBSchema file for the referenced databases. Add that DBSchema file as a database reference inside the project. That will avoid trying to point to another project and creating a circular reference. You can generate the DBSchema files using VSDBCMD.exe with the "import" option to create the file from a database.

You may want to watch for errors on build. We had to build/deploy a database multiple times for a "new" build because of those circular references. The first time with drop/create for DB A, then create DB B, then update DB A. If we didn't, the objects depending on the other database wouldn't get created.